# Visunal Basic net 2008 a game with picture boxes

Tags: vb.net

Hi Im making a game like dance dance revolution but in arrow keys I had a incident before where the vb net stop reading my designer.vb so I recopy the code to another new form and made a design again. Basically what I want is when the moving arrow hit the stationary arrow it should say good and it works fine though but there is this perfect hit where the player hit an arrow exaclty in the middle it use to work before the incident but now it doesnt can anyone help or suggest a new idea how.

```
'Perfect Hit
        If (RArrowDown.Top = ArrowDown.Top) And RArrowDown.Visible = True Then
            TimerMain.Enabled = False
            Hit += 1
            Score += 33
            RArrowDown.Visible = False
            Perfect.Visible = True
            TimerPerfect.Enabled = True
            Combo_Counter += 1
            RandomTime_1.Enabled = True
        End If
        'Good Hit
        If (RArrowDown.Top <= ArrowDown.Height + ArrowDown.Top) And RArrowDown.Visible = True Then
            TimerMain.Enabled = False
            Hit += 1
            Score += 10
            RArrowDown.Visible = False
            Good.Visible = True
            TimerGood.Enabled = True
            Combo_Counter += 1
            RandomTime_1.Enabled = True
        End If
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: "it use to work before the incident but now it doesnt can anyone help or suggest a new idea how."  If the code is the same then the design of the form must have changed.  Perhaps you don't have your arrow thingies perfectly aligned anymore?

Comment: Yeah I already checked that and its perfectly align